# Triggering click on form submit button in Angular 2/4 forms causing issues in edge browser

Tags: angular, microsoft-edge, angular-forms, angular-schema-form

I have a scenario where I need my form submit to be called via code, since my submit button is **hidden** from view. I have a logic to invoke button click (one common button for all forms) using the below logic.

```js
const element = 
  this._elementRef.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('personal-btn');
if (element && element[0]) {
  element[0].click();
}
```

My Form :

```html
<json-schema-form [widgets]="customWidgets" 
  [framework]="selectedFrameWork" 
  [form]="jsonFormObject" 
  [options]="jsonFormOptions" 
  (onChanges)="onChanges($event)" (valueChanges)="changeInputValue($event)"
  (onSubmit)="saveInfo($event)" 
  (valueChanges)="changeInputValue($event)">
</json-schema-form>
```

My Form submit :

```html
<div class="d-none">
  <input aria-describedby="control52Status" class="personal-btn btn btn- 
    primary float-right" id="control52"
    name="undefined" type="submit" value="undefined">
</div>
```

The issue that I am facing is that, when I click on the next button (form submit logic is called via code), form submission takes place and the form input values get *appended* to the *current URL* rather than internal logic taking place and page refreshes.

Example :

```html
[site url]?name=test123
```

But when I remove **hide** property on my submit button and eventually click on that submit button, the form gets submitted properly without URL appending and page refresh.

I am not facing this issue in any browsers other than edge.

My issue is just the same as this: [Stop "?" from being added to URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38707876/stop-from-being-added-to-url)

But none of the preventDefault or return false solutions helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to change the type of **next** button as **button**

Like;

```
<button type="button"></button>
```

Comment: `<button role="button" tabindex="0" (click)="submitInformation($event)" type="button" class="btn btn-primary col col-sm-auto">
                    Submit
                </button>`

Comment: If I am not wrong this is your submit button, I need to see the "next" button. Also the "submit" button's type must be "submit" other than "button".

Comment: This is the Next button actually, worded as Submit since there are multiple forms in this page that get submitted.

Comment: Ok, can i see your submit button with **hide** property?

Comment: `<div class="d-none">
  <input aria-describedby="control52Status" class="personal-btn btn btn- 
    primary float-right" id="control52"
    name="undefined" type="submit" value="undefined">
</div>`

Comment: Can you try to change **d-none** to Angular's **[hide]** attribute or ***ngIf**

Comment: Ok, i'm trying my last chance :) Can you upload your code (of course not all) to https://stackblitz.com. I am quite curious about the cause of this problem.

Comment: This was the solution in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could try to use the "button" type button, then in the button click event, you could use the [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) Post method to submit the form data.